# Tensorflow: loading, saving time

Tags: tensorflow, resuming-training

I have four different models with same structures, which are used as a predictor in the "main" problem. Each time in "main" problem I call one of them to provide the prediction. Also, using the new observation, I updates the weights of the each network.

Currently, in order to differentiate between the models I save them in four different `ckpt` models, then I load them each time to do prediction or updating it. When the network is updated, I save it again.

This procedure works good. The problem is that initializing the variables, loading the model, and saving it again is too expensive. Each time I call the network to update, it takes about 10 seconds which around 1 second is for training and the reminder of time is for initializing, loading and saving.

As another approach, I tried to have the model stayed in memory. But, since I have one `dnn.py`, which I call it for each of the four problems, the name of the variables, parameters, etc. are the same. So, `TensorFlow` get confused about them, and it just does not work.
Since I may have more than four predictors, (even like 22), it is not reasonable to create four different `dnn.py` with different name of variables.

I would appreciate any help to write the procedure in an efficient way.

Best,

Afshin

Comment: Reading variables from disk for each training step sounds inefficient, you should reorganize your network to keep those values in memory, ie, by using variable_scope to keep different sets of variables separate

Comment: Hi, @YaroslavBulatov - could you copy that to an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading variables from disk for each training step sounds inefficient, you should reorganize your network to keep those values in memory, ie, by using variable_scope to keep different sets of variables separate